# WCF service wsdl client error

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF web service written in .NET 4.5 which is working fine.

The client I am using to call it (a SQL CLR stored procedure) has to use .NET 2 because it's for a Sql Server (2005).

When I test the web service using the built in WCF test client, everything works fine. Likewise, if I build a client using .NET 3+ with svcutil.exe it also works.

However, since I have to use .NET 2 the only solution I found was to use wsdl.exe to generate the client ([original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14649752/1324019)) - which it did successfully, except I haven't manage to get it working.

I get the error `The message with Action 'action removed' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).`

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5487791/1324019), however it recommends looking into the `EndpointDispatcher`  class which I'm not using since I'm on .NET 2.0.

As far as I know all of my namespaces are the same - yet still no luck. I have also tried using the service trace utility but it doesn't seem to show me anything useful.

Is it even possible to use a client made in this manner with a service this way? Or are the endpoints permanently incompatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up regenerating my client with wsdl on the off chance I'd changed something, turns out I had. The client updated my namespaces and everything worked from that point on.